# Why would the VSC IDE Not ignore the commented out code?

Tags: php, comments

Why would the VSC IDE Not ignore the commented-out code?
As I understand it, an object property of an object is accessed like this:

```
$parentobj->$daughterobj.
```

So, this should be OK. I have an index page that builds a table.

````
  @foreach($events as $event)
     <tr>
      <td>{{ $event->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->eventTitle }}</td>
      <td>{{ substr($event->eventDescription, 0, 24)}}</td>
      
      {{-- the IDE trips on the next line, Undefined variable: memory. -->
      
      <td>{{ $event->$memory->id}}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->$memory->memTitle}}</td>
      <td>{{ substr($event->$memory->memBody,0,24)}}</td>```
      **{{-- if I comment them with {{--   --}} it still complains about the Undefined variable: memory**
      
      ```<td>{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->created_at)) }}</td>
          
      <td>
          <a href="show/{{$event->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Show</a>
          <a href="event/{{$event->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
          <form action="/postmem/{{$event->id}}" method="post" class="d-inline">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              @method('DELETE')
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
          </form>
      </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
````

Can someone tell me why the IDE is reading commented out lines?

Comment: Which templating system are you using? What is the file extension of your file?

Comment: Laravel 8, blade files.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using the wrong commenting characters. Should be `<!--`  `-->`, not `{!--` `--}`. Bad me.

Comment: could you expand the answer with the particular place where you've made the error?

Comment: I was trying different ways of coding a loop in html, trying to get  my view to work,